# Display multiple formats of videos on my web site which are stored in shared folder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have requirement that user will upload different formats of videos which include(.mp4,.flv,.mov,.wmv,.avi,.mp3)  and we need to show all different type of videos in a page.we are storing user uploaded files out side the application(shared path). I am displaying videos dynamically  using html5 video tag.

### The following code was used to display videos

```
string contentType = "", extension = "";
if (dtrow["extension"].ToString() == ".mp4")
{
contentType = "data:video/mp4;base64,";
extension = dtrow["extension"].ToString().Replace(".", "");
}
if (dtrow["extension"].ToString() == ".avi")
{
contentType = "data:video/avi;base64,";
extension = dtrow["extension"].ToString().Replace(".", "");
}
if (dtrow["extension"].ToString() == ".flv")
{
contentType = "data:video/flv;base64,";
extension = dtrow["extension"].ToString().Replace(".", "");
}


HtmlGenericControl fileDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");                               

fileDiv.ID = "fileDivVideo" + i + j;
fileDiv.Attributes.Add("Class", "row-fluid data-fields noPrint");
fileDiv.Attributes.Add("Style", "margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px");
HtmlGenericControl Video = new HtmlGenericControl("Video");
Video.ID = "Video" + i + j;
Video.InnerText = dtrow["Name"].ToString();
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dtrow["videoPah"].ToString());
string base64String = contentType + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, 
bytes.Length);
Video.Attributes.Add("src", base64String);
Video.Attributes.Add("style", "height:300px;width:100%");
Video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/" + extension);
Video.Attributes.Add("controls", "controls");
fileDiv.Controls.Add(Video);
DocsDiv.Controls.Add(fileDiv);
```

---

i am having following problems

1. only mp4 videos are displaying and for remaining blank space is showing.
2. When more videos need to display then page loading takes lot of time.
3. Can i directly display files from path (shared path not from application directory) irrespective of reading the video as bytes.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default way of html5 video, instead of use byte array of video file. Replace this part of your code:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dtrow["videoPah"].ToString());
string base64String = contentType + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, 
 bytes.Length);
Video.Attributes.Add("src", base64String);
```

to this:

```
HtmlGenericControl source = new HtmlGenericControl("source");
source.Attributes.Add("src", THE_FILE_ADDRESS);
source.Attributes.Add("type", "video/" + VIDEO_TYPE);
Video.Controls.Add(source);
```

Comment: I have stored my files in application directory and accesed files using application directory path.is working fine and loding faster then converting files into byte stream.
my question is to As i am saving upload files in application directory when deployment is going the file will be removed.
Can i save iimages ,videos,fies in separate virtual directory and access them in current appliation.

Comment: I think this is your answer: https://serverfault.com/a/637690 . And If my answer did help you, Please point it by upvote / accept .